# Pojo to Json, if Pojo has embedded objects

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jakarta-ee, gson

I have a two POJO classes: `AddressInformation` and `PackageInformation` (with their getters and setters which are not specified in the below code).

```
public class AddressInformation {
    private Integer address_id;
    private String street_name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Integer zipcode;
}

public class PackageInformation {

    private Integer packageId;
    private Integer packageType;
    private Double packageWeight;
    private AddressInformation packageSource;
    private AddressInformation packageDestination;
}
```

I am persisting the instances of the classes using hibernate, and trying to retrieve the contents of `PackageInformation` from the database using hibernate and return the contents as JSON format. I am not using any framework.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<PackageInformation> packagelist = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    packagelist = session.createQuery("FROM PackageInformation").list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
```

I wanted the `packagelist` which has the collection of PackageInformation to be converted to JSON.

The catch here is that `PackageInformation` object has AddressInformation embedded in to it.

I tried the below code to convert the collection of PackageInformation to JSON:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try{
        for(PackageInformation pack : packagelist){

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            AddressInformation sourceAddress = pack.getPackageSource();
            JsonElement sourceAddressJson =  gson.toJsonTree(sourceAddress);
            jsonObj.put("sourceAddress",sourceAddressJson);
            AddressInformation destinationAddress = pack.getPackageDestination();
            JsonElement destinationeAddressJson =  gson.toJsonTree(destinationAddress);
            jsonObj.put("destinationAddress",destinationeAddressJson);
            jsonObj.put("package_id",pack.getPackageId());
            jsonObj.put("package_type",pack.getPackageType());
            jsonObj.put("package_weight",pack.getPackageWeight());
         }
        returnString = json.toString();
    }catch(JSONException je){
            returnString = je.toString();
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(returnString).build();
```

But I do not get JSON with `sourceAddress` and `destinationAddress` details embedded as JSON. Instead I got black fields: the `sourceAddress` and `destinationAddress` details are missing as in the JSON below.

```
 [
  {
   "sourceAddress": {},
   "destinationAddress: {},
   "package_id": 1,
   "package_type": 1,
   "package_weight": 500,
  }
  {
   "sourceAddress": {},
   "destinationAddress: {},
   "package_id": 2,
   "package_type": 5,
   "package_weight": 700,
  }
 ]
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

To answer straight to your question, I think that your `AddressInformation` fields are **empty** (not null, just empty objects) so you are missing some points into your hibernate calls.

However, you can try to serialize all your stuff in another way that is more simple and safe. You are using `JsonElement` and `JsonObject` that I consider "low level" respect to the services that Gson provides to you.

I want to use my example also to show you at the same time the effect of an empty object, so compare source to destination addresses in the final JSON. This is my proposal.

```
public class PackageInformation {

    @SerializedName("package_id")
    Integer packageId;

    @SerializedName("package_type")
    Integer packageType;

    @SerializedName("package_weight")
    Double packageWeight;

    @SerializedName("sourceAddress")
    AddressInformation packageSource;

    @SerializedName("destinationAddress")
    AddressInformation packageDestination;
}
```

As you can note, I added the `@SerializedName` annotation to change the name of serialized field (this is why, I think, you are using this approach). Then I use the simpliest serialization method the Gson provides you with.

```
public class Q19615935 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<PackageInformation> list = new ArrayList<PackageInformation>();

       PackageInformation pi = new PackageInformation();
       pi.packageId = 42;
       pi.packageType = 21;
       pi.packageWeight = 2000.0;

       AddressInformation source = new AddressInformation();
       source.address_id = 1;
       source.city="A city";
       source.state="A state";
       source.street_name="A street name";
       source.zipcode=0;

       pi.packageSource= source;
       pi.packageDestination=new AddressInformation();

       list.add(pi);

       Gson g = new Gson();
       System.out.println(g.toJson(list));


    }

}
```

Since I do not have your db, I built a list by hands and this is my result (I formatted the console result):

```
[
    {
        "package_id": 42, 
        "package_type": 21, 
        "package_weight": 2000, 
        "sourceAddress": {
            "address_id": 1, 
            "street_name": "A street name", 
            "city": "A city", 
            "state": "A state", 
            "zipcode": 0
        }, 
        "destinationAddress": { }
    }
]
```

My conclusions:

1. If source and destination are not empty objects, you should use my serialization code.
2. If they are empty, you should check how they come from db and once solved, check again point 1.